# log4net date format defaulting to Iso8601DateFormatter despite specifying conversion pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I need to format the date as Mar-07-2016 05:00:00 PM

My web.config has the following entry

```
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

But still the log shows this format: 2016-03-07 17:00:00.000

Comment: Please try: %d{MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss}

Comment: @BalaSakthis didn't work. got same default format: 2016-03-08 10:33:49.000

Comment: BTW I also subscribed to the log4net mailing list and posted the same question there yesterday. haven't got any reply yet.

Comment: Are you logging to a text file or SQL table or what?

Comment: @BBauer42 SQL Server database

Comment: Then I believe Peter's answer below is probably correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging to the db type DateTime. So when you are reading from your database you can format the column in any format you want. The log4net conversion pattern only tell how to format the string for the insert sql statement. When you do a formatting without the millisecond you will miss them in you db when you want to do a order. So I recommend to add the milliseconds to the data field in the table.

In your select statement from the db you can do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), date, 126) FROM MyLogTable
```

Comment: I guess if I really needed a custom date format I need to change the column type in db to string.